# Alternating ethernet adapter settings?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet, adapter

I dual boot into Win-7 to run my Ethernet CNC Mill. Sometimes I need to use the same Ethernet Port to access the internet but this requires resetting my Ethernet Adapter Settings.

Network and Internet -> Network Connections -> CncMill Unidentified Network Intel(R) Ethernet Connection 1217-LM

Is there a way to have two versions of these Ethernet settings (Mill & Internet) so I can enable/disable them as required? Thanks - Alex.

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html

Comment: @AlexFisher do you have one physical Ethernet port in your PC? Also you may use a home router to connect both PC and Mill.

Comment: Hi David, yes I have one physical Ethernet port. I want to connect my Cnc motion controller directly to my Ethernet port to minimise errors. This requires swapping the available socket between my router and motion controller.

Answer (score 0):

@alexfisher You can add a secondary IP address to your network connection, main static IP address for the CNC mill and the secondary IP address for your internet connection.
Connect the CNC and get the IP address that the computer is using, then connect the computer to internet and get the IP address it is using, use both IP addresses as static IP addresses, please see picture at the end of this post.
You do this on the properties of internet connection.
When using CNC mill plug the cable in it, when using the internet plug in the cable in the router or the network point on the wall and it should work, tested on Laptop used to run Laser Cutter and internet, also tested on desktop running restaurant tills and internet.
I hope it works for you.
See screenshot below:

[IPV4 Internet settings using two different IP Addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilSjf.png)